# Duplicate symbols when running in release mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am including two libraries in my app via cocoa pods. We'll call them XMLParser and StoreService. The StoreService library already uses XMLParser though, so it causes duplicate symbol errors.

I followed these [instructions](http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries/) and was able to remove XMLParser from the StoreService library.

This worked fine for Debug mode, but when I run in Release mode, I still get the duplicate symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you didn't completely follow those instructions. Libraries can have multiple architecture slices. If you stripped only the active architecture, that will take care of Debug, but it won't take care of Release because it adds architectures (because Build Active Architecture Only is No). So that would explain your differing results in Debug and Release.

Comment: I stripped all of the architectures that lipo told me were there (i386, x86_64, armv7, and arm64).

I'm not sure what else I would need to do to make sure that release is gone.

Comment: Never mind. I somehow missed one of the architectures.

Comment: All too easy to do. :)